# Disable Eclipse plugins?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I'm running latest version of Eclipse (Indigo) for Java Development.  By default it comes with a bunch of plugins we don't need or want.  How do I disable or uninstall them?  The uninstall button is greyed out in 'About->Installation details'

For example, I wish to disable these:

> Maven
>
> GIT
>
> Usage

We use Ant and Perforce, so no reason to have these.

In the Maven and the Usage, it keeps 'updating indexes' in background which is killing the bandwidth here. Even though we disabled all the downloading in the preference (Usage respects this, but it seems Maven is just ignoring the settings).  For GIT, it seems buggy and is throwing errors on startup; even after a clean/fresh install.

Again, we don't use or want these.  They cause nothing but problems and we're better off with out them, how to get rid of them?

Comment: That is the maven plugin.  Get the Java EE distribution - it doesn't have the maven plugin.

Comment: Indigo "base" does not ship a GIT plugin per default, maybe you downloaded the wrong version?

Comment: Indigo "For Java Developers" does have git: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/indigosr1

Comment: JavaEE dist comes with even more junk: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigosr1 - seriously, who still uses CVS; does everyone really need that by default?

Comment: Do I want Eclipse Classic? http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-371/indigosr1

Comment: Just download the 'classic' version and manually install those plugins you need... btw: any issue having plugins on board you don't really need?

Comment: Classic has the least junk with it.  Starting from there and adding plugins as needed (as stated by @home) seems to be a good technique.  Here is the comparison chart: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php

Answer (score 4):

To uninstall them just go to Help->Software Updates... got to the Installed Software tab ('What is already installed' link in newer versions) and uninstall the ones you don't need.

Edit: Just saw you mentioning that they are greyed out... This might be a bit more dangerous but you could just try deleting them from eclipse/features and then from eclipse/plugins.

Edit2: Another option is preferences->General->Startup and Shutdown and unselect them.